# Safari shows blank page IOS 12 for some sites

Tags: ios, apache, safari

As of IOS 12, apparently Apple has changed things such that some websites serving HTTP2 will display only blank pages. This blows up any browser on IOS 12, including Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a webmaster, it's related to your server sending the "Upgrade: h2" response header. Your server shouldn't be sending that header.

For a fix in Apache: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59311

For a fix in nginx: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/915